# "module initialization " in AWS lambada

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have created a SQS queue and now i want to read the data from my lambada function.I have configured the trigger from SQS to this lambada function.

When i put the message in SQS Queue it shows me 1 message in Flight.But when i click test in lambda function it give me

Error

```
  {
       "errorMessage": "module initialization error"
  }
```

I am using below boto3

```
  import boto3
  sqs = boto3.client('sqs')
  queue_url = 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/944198216610/My-Queue'

  response = sqs.receive_message(

       QueueUrl='https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/944198216610/My-Queue',

       AttributeNames=[
      'SentTimestamp'],

       MaxNumberOfMessages=1,

       MessageAttributeNames=[
       'All'
        ],

       VisibilityTimeout=0,
        WaitTimeSeconds=0

       )

      message = response['Messages'][0]

      receipt_handle = message['ReceiptHandle']

      # Delete received message from queue
      sqs.delete_message(
      QueueUrl='https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/944198216610/My-Queue',
      ReceiptHandle=receipt_handle

        )


        print('Received and deleted message: %s' % message)
```

Comment: If you click "test" in the console then you aren't getting anything from the queue, but instead are sending it a test event. Do you see any error in CloudWatch logs for the lambda from an SQS event (not the test event)? Also, you should redact information such as you account number.

Comment: You should have more information in the 'Log output' section

Comment: Hi Deiv,I have integarted my SQS with lambada.So when i am posting the message in SQS i am getting this error.  module initialization error: 'Messages'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code calls sqs.receive_message, however to properly integrate Lambda with SQS you can use Lambda event triggers. This way, whenever an event goes into the queue, SQS will automatically invoke your Lambda function with that event (or multiple events based on specified batch size).

[See here for setting up an SQS Lambda event trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#events-sqs-eventsource)

[Also see here for setting up a Lambda handler in python](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-programming-model-handler-types.html) where the event parameter will be the event SQS triggers your lambda with (print it and see the format of the event so you can get an idea of how to use the event data).

This way, when you send a message to SQS, SQS will trigger your Lambda function, and if your Lambda returns successfully, SQS will remove the message from the queue. You don't need to do receive_message or delete_message manually.

Comment: Hi Deiv, Thanks for your reply.I got your point to use method lambada_handler and then receive data in event.But just wondering what is wrong with the above code it should also work right ? Appreciate if you can help me figure out.

Comment: You're welcome. Your core logic does look fine, however Lambda looks for a handler module whenever it gets triggered, that includes test triggers through the console, and that's most likely why you got the "module initialization error". So in theory if you put this code inside a lambda_handler as described in the docs it should work, however it is best to use the built in triggers as mentioned earlier and let aws manage the queue, less hassle for you. Good luck!